# Visual Studio and GIT ot letting me change branches due to changes when i have no changes

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and Git extension. I have been having a random issue where I will do my pulls, then pushes after comitting some changes, and then Git will not let me change branches. The error it gives me is as follows:

> Cannot switch to beta because there are uncommitted changes. Commit or undo your changes before you switch branches. See the Output window for details.

Now, I have ran many syncs, pulls etc. I still keep getting this error so am not able to change my branches. I also used GIT in a CMD console, to make sure everything was up to date and had no changes. I ran the following commands and got the following returned:

> C:\Users\casey.pharr\Source>cd Repos/
>
> C:\Users\casey.pharr\Source\Repos>cd "TAM Rewrite"
>
> C:\Users\casey.pharr\Source\Repos\TAM Rewrite>cd "TAM Rewrite"
>
> C:\Users\casey.pharr\Source\Repos\TAM Rewrite\TAM Rewrite>git fetch
> origin alpha From
> https://trescal-hart.visualstudio.com/_git/TAM%20Rewrite  * branch
> alpha      -> FETCH_HEAD
>
> C:\Users\casey.pharr\Source\Repos\TAM Rewrite\TAM Rewrite>git pull
> origin alpha From
> https://trescal-hart.visualstudio.com/_git/TAM%20Rewrite  * branch
> alpha      -> FETCH_HEAD Already up-to-date.
>
> C:\Users\casey.pharr\Source\Repos\TAM Rewrite\TAM Rewrite>git push
> alpha fatal: 'alpha' does not appear to be a git repository fatal:
> Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
> exists.
>
> C:\Users\casey.pharr\Source\Repos\TAM Rewrite\TAM Rewrite>git push
> origin alpha Everything up-to-date
>
> C:\Users\casey.pharr\Source\Repos\TAM Rewrite\TAM Rewrite>

I do not understand how to correct this. I have rebooted, and even restarted Visual Studio many times. Last time this happen, I had to delete my local repo and clone the remote repo locally, to start a fresh copy. But now it is doing this again and I do not want to nor should have to do that. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please execute `git status` and if you feel the need afterwards, post the results to your question.

Comment: Thank you so much! I di not know that, as I always use the GUI in VS for GIT.

Comment: Now, there are some changes to commit in there, but are file deletes. How do I get GIT to update everything correctly to recognize these that were returned in 'git status', or will that now take care of it to be recognized?

Comment: Also, take care to format your questions correctly, in particular if you're pasting code, indent the text by 4 spaces instead of using `>`, this will correctly handle special characters that markdown/html would otherwise process, as well as preserve newlines correctly.

Comment: I think here is where do the 'git reset head <FILE>. Thanks so much again!

Comment: Yea I was in huge hurry. Normally do format cleaner. Thanks again for everything.

Comment: `git status` only lists information about your repository and working folder back to you, it does not fix/change anything at all, so any problems you had with git checkout or similar beforehand will exist afterwards, the difference is that you can see what the problem is.